# Change default icon creating a new Android Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse

Does anyone knows how to change the default icon that is embbeded here? In order that **all new applications** that you create **has that icon instead the android default one**.

[image]

I tried to look for it into /android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-[VERSION]/data without success. :( Is it named ic_launcher.png?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Please read before vote or answer. Is not how to change the icon app, this Q is about how to make it default for ALL new projects.

:)

Comment: use browse for ur icon

Comment: why do you want to change the default. just browse for a new image each time.

Comment: I'm trying to do change the base default icon in order to make easier this selection for a 20 people working group. I dont want to browse each time we create a project. It's like the script creation: you loose 2h creating some script that saves you 2min per day. :)

Comment: Why blind downvotes? First read the question and then think for what the user has asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the interest of everyone:

The default icons are in this path:

```
/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_xxxxx.jar/templates/
```

Here you can define also a new default package and a header for ALL your activities.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to change your launcher icon just modifying your *manifest.xml*; Please refer to [http://developer.android.com/](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)

This way you can have a different icon for each project. If you just want to change the default one I dont see what is the purpose of it but maybe it is defined in your adtbundle here: ***\YOUR ADT BUNDLE\sdk\tools\apps\SdkController\res***

Comment: My purpose is to has the same launcher icon for each project we create in my co. 

Make it without any kind of icon browsing. :)